# Put hierarchy in its own separate dimension or set it as a part of related dimension?

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling

I'm new to `the dimensional model` in dataware house design, and I face some confusion in my first design.

I take a simple business process (`Vacation Request`), and I want to ask which of these two designs is accurate and near to be effective and applicable, I will be grateful if I get a detailed answer please? (My question about the dimension design mainly)

```
1- 

Dimension.Employee           Fact.Vacation
[Employee Key]               [Employee Key] FK PK
[_source key]                [Vacation Transaction]PK DD
[Employee Name]              ...
....                         ...
[Campus Code]
[Campus Name]
[Department Code]
[Department Name]
[Section code]
[Section Name]
....
```

---

```
2- 

Dimension.Employee           Dimension.Section         Fact.Vacation
[Employee Key]               [Section Key]             [Employee Key] FK PK
[_source key]                [_source key]             [Vacation Transaction]PK DD
[Employee Name]              [Department Code]         [Section Key]FK
....                         [Department Name]         ...
....                         [Campus Code]
                             [Campus Name]
```

---

Where the hierarchy is like this:

```
Campus Contains --> 
Many Departments and each department contains --> 
many sections and each section contains many employees
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question! I've faced this situation a number of times myself. I'm afraid this is going to get a bit confusing and the final answer will be, "it depends", but here are some things to consider...

- WHAT A STAR SCHEMA REALLY IS: While people think of a data warehouse as a reporting database, it actually performs two functions: data integration and data distribution. It turns out that the best data structures for integration are not great for distribution (here's a [blog post](https://dataspace.com/big-data-strategy/star-schema-data-mart-yes-data-warehouse-no/) I wrote about this some years ago). Star schemas are really about data distribution - getting data out of the system quickly and easily. The best data structures for this have no joins, i.e. they are akin to flat files (yes, I realize there are some DB buffering considerations that might affect this a bit but, in a general sense, indexed flat files do avoid all joins).

The star schema takes that flat file and normalizes it a little, largely to save disk space (it's a huge space waster when you have to write out every attribute of each dimension on every record). So, when people say a star schema is denormalized, they are partially incorrect. The dimension tables are denormalized (snowflake schemas normalize these) but the fact table is normalized - it's got a bunch of attributes dependent on a unique primary key.

So, this concept would point to minimizing the number of dimensions in order to minimize the number of joins you need to make. Point for putting them into **one dimension**.

- FACT TABLE SHOWS RELATIONSHIPS: Your fact table shows the relationship between otherwise unrelated dimension elements. For example, in the absence of a sale, there is no relationship between a product and a customer. A sale creates that relationship and the sale fact record models it. In your case, there is a natural relationship between section and employee (I assume, at least). You don't need a fact table to model this relationship and, therefore, they should both be in one dimension table. Another point for putting them into **one dimension**.
- CAN AN EMPLOYEE BE IN MULTIPLE SECTIONS SIMULTANEOUSLY?: If an employee can be in multiple sections at the same time then you probably do need the fact table to model this relationship (otherwise, each employee would need two active records in the employee dimension table). Point for putting them into **separate dimensions**.
- DO EMPLOYEES CHANGE SECTIONS FREQUENTLY?: If so, and you only have one dimension, you'll end up having to constantly be modifying the employee record in your employee dimension - this leads to a longer than needed dimension table if this is a type two slowly changing dimension (i.e. one where you're tracking the history of changes to dimension elements). Point for putting them into **separate dimensions**.
- DO YOU NEED TO AGGREGATE BY SECTION?: If you have a lot of sections and frequently report at the section level, you may need to create a fact table aggregated at the section level. In this case, if you're a staunch believer in having your DB enforce your relationships (I am), you'll need a section table to which your fact table can relate. In this case you'll need a section table. Point for putting them into **separate dimensions**.
- WILL THE SECTION DIMENSION BE USED BY OTHER FACT TABLES?: One tough situation with star schemas occurs when you're using conformed dimensions (i.e. dimensions that are shared by multiple fact tables). The problem occurs when the different fact tables are defined at different levels in the dimension hierarchy. In your case, imagine there is a different fact table, say one modeling equipment purchases and it only makes sense at the section, not the employee, level. In this case, you'd probably split the section dimension into its own table so it can be shared by both fact tables, your current one and that future, equipment one. This, BTW, is similar to the consideration related to aggregate tables mentioned earlier. Point for putting them into **separate dimensions**.

Anyhow, that's off the top of my head. So, I guess the answer is, "it depends". Both will work, it just depends on other factors you're trying to optimize for. I'll try to edit my answer if anything else comes to mind. Best of luck with this!

Comment: Thank U so much for your explanation, But Could I ask if there are conflict factors like my case which your rule 1 and some other rules applied to it! then which scenario should I select safely?

Comment: My pleasure! Can you provide a little more detail? What conflicts do you anticipate? Ultimately, if one method won't work then you are better off using the other method rather than forcing a bad solution. If neither of them work well, perhaps you need something completely different.

Comment: Thanks a lot, What I mean that, U give us some helpful tips to recognize different scenarios and select the correct one, What if two conflicted tips are applied successfully, which one is more appropriate, like in my example the vacation request business process, in which tip1,3,4 are passed successfully! Should I align with the suggestion of @Ron Dunn `Employees are a WHO, departments are a WHERE.`? in this case

Comment: It seems like either would work for you (one of my issues with star schemas is that their design can be very subjective). Anything you can do with one dimension will always work by breaking them into multiple dimensions. The problem is architects randomly creating dimensions (ultimately, you could put each field into its own dimension) and, thus, joins. If you'll be reporting vacation requests by section frequently, then I'd probably break it into a separate dimension. If you're usually at the employee level, though, and section just describes the employee, I'd likely leave them in one.

Comment: Should I put in my consideration during design that the dimension table have to be designed in a manner that make it easily shared across multiple business processes not just the vacation request business process?

Comment: I think so. In fact,I was just about to add another consideration to my answer that, if I'm interpreting you correctly, addresses that point.

Comment: One more question please, If I decide to create a separate section dimension, Shoud I set  a relationship with the employee dimension, I mean (section key) as FK in the employee table or just use it as a FK in the fact table, I'm a little confused, and this made me thinking about other things like the contract, Should I create a separate contract table as a dimension or it's  okay to set the contract data in the employee dim table?

Comment: Interesting point. If folks will query the employee dimension without using the fact table (eg to show counts of employees by section) then you'll need to do this (assuming you don't keep everything in one dimension). Alternatively, you could create a new fact table that ties employees to sections with a snapshot taken every day - purists might recommend that but it seems like a lot of unnecessary work to me. Regarding contract, are you referring to contract employees? Do they share the same attributes as normal employees? If so, then I might put them in there. But, do they even get vacations?

Comment: Thanks a lot, By contract I mean the job contract and every set of employees has the same contract type.

Comment: So, the contract represents the job that the employee is working on? If employees change contracts frequently, it sounds like contract is a separate dimension. I'd think there'd be a lot of other stuff you'd like to track about contracts, too (start date, end date, etc.). So, if I understand contract properly, it sounds to me like a separate dimension. For current purposes, are contracts related to vacation requests?

Comment: Contract is the agreement between the employee and the organization, and it’s not related to the vacation but the business user may want to know the number of vacations based on the contracts rather than the sections, and because every contract type grant a specific number of vacation days per year for the employee , the business user can know info about the percentage of unused vacation days.

Comment: Well, it does seem like contract needs a relationship to employee. Once again you can integrate it with employee but will you ever need it to be independent? Will you ever need a fact table at the contract level? Unused vacation days could be interesting. How will you track the grant of days to each employee? Are grants always at the start of the year or are they based on employee start date or something else? I'd recommend thinking that through as it could affect how you want to model contract (can you see what I mean by star schemas are very subjective?).

Comment: I think U meant by ‘integrate’ it with employee to set both in the same dim, Am I right? . I think the employee level is the lowest level ever so adding the contract doesn’t affect the granularity of the fact table! U are totally right the grants are based on the contract type, some contracts the grants from the contract date, some contracts are from the year beginning, it’s so important question. Could i ask what’s convenient in this case create a separate dimension table or in one dim?

Comment: Yep, I did mean integrate into the same dim. Easier is bit tough to say with confidence but it's probably easier to just have one dimension rather than two. It will mean a bit more  complexity in your ETL job to populate the dimension but, at the same time, it also means that you needn't look up the contract key for every new fact record you load. So, a single dim is probably easiest, so long as it satisfies all your use cases. In the worst case, you can experiment by doing it as one and breaking it up later if it's causing trouble.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations, I’ll be so grateful if you could recommend some resources, courses in addition to the Kimball bible to help me resolving my design issues.

Comment: You're welcome! TBH, much of my knowledge comes from trial and error over the past 30 years, rather than from books. I'd recommend starting with Kimball's books. After that, I'd likely check Google as well as some LinkedIn groups.  You may also find a few, short postings on my company's blog but they won't be super deep. Just make sure that whatever you read, you can justify it in your mind, you can picture how you'll implement it, and you can see how it'll fit future requirements that you can envision.

Answer (score 1):

The second.

Employees are a WHO, departments are a WHERE.